# Odoo: is it possible to color Many2Many field by function?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

i want to colorize this cells, module is "Calendar".

[image]

also, this place in views:
[image]
i can do this with adding

```
options='{"color_field":"color"}'
```

to field parameters, but it need to calculate color by checking, is attendee accepted or declined. If accepted, color - green, if decline - red.
I can check this in field

```
attendee_ids = fields.One2many(
        'calendar.attendee', 'event_id', 'Participant')
```

also attendee model
[image]
How can i realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new widget that inherits the `many2manyattendee` to color tags based on the attendee `state` field

You will need to define the name of the color field and set its value for each attendee (tag)

***Example:*** (*many2manyattendee.js*)

```
/** @odoo-module **/

import fieldRegistry from 'web.field_registry';
import relationalFields from 'web.relational_fields';


const STATE_SELECTION = new Map([
    ['needsAction', 0],
    ['tentative', 2],
    ['declined', 1],
    ['accepted', 10]
]);

const Many2ManyAttendeeColored = fieldRegistry.get("many2manyattendee").extend({
    _renderTags: function () {
        var self = this;
        var context = this._getRenderTagsContext();
        this.colorField = 'state_index';
        context.elements.forEach(function(item) {
            item[self.colorField] = STATE_SELECTION.get(self.record.specialData.partner_ids.find(partner => partner.id === item.id).status);
        });
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },
});

fieldRegistry.add('many2many_attendee_colored', Many2ManyAttendeeColored);
```

To load the JS code, add the following entry to the manifest file:

```
    'assets': {
        'web.assets_backend': [
            'MODULE_NAME/static/src/js/many2manyattendee.js',

        ],
    }
```

To use it, change the widget on the partners' field to `many2many_attendee_colored`

Comment: can you please watch this issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73183584/odoo-how-in-js-file-get-record-from-db-then-change-it-and-re-write
maybe you know, how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a color field on model `calendar.attendee` which is the model `attendee_ids` is related to. The many2many color widget is using integers which are not easy to change IIRC. But for the color field itself should be easy:

```py
class Attendee(models.Model):
    _inherit = "calendar.attendee"
    STATE_COLOR_MAPPING = {
        "needsAction": 0,
        "tentative": 1,
        "declined": 2,
        "accepted": 3,
    }

    color = fields.Integer(compute="_compute_color")

    @api.depends("state")
    def _compute_color(self):
        for attendee in self:
            attendee.color = self.STATE_COLOR_MAPPING.get(attendee.state)
```

You just have to find out if color index are static and if the possible colors are enough for you.