# Odoo: how in *.js file get record from db, then change it and re-write?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-15

I added new settings for user by inheriting "res.users" model:

```
calendar_scale_type = fields.Selection([
        ('day', 'Day'),
        ('week', 'Week'),
        ('month', 'Month'),
        ('year', 'Year')],
        'Type of calendar scaling', default='week')
```

in calendar view i want to read this field and set scale_type when opening this form
[image]
here in calendar_model.js file i want to read this setting from current user
[image]

and also rewrite current user setting if he chooses diferent type of scale here
[image]

how can i do this? i tried to use rpc, but i do something wrong and it didn`t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [session_info](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/models/ir_http.py#L25) and add `calendar_scale_type` to use it later in the calendar model (You will need to override the [setScale](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/views/calendar/calendar_model.js#L349) function).

***Example:***

1. Add `calendar_scale_type` to the session info:

   ```
   class Http(models.AbstractModel):
       _inherit = 'ir.http'

       def session_info(self):
           session_info = super(Http, self).session_info()
           session_info['calendar_scale_type'] = self.env.user.calendar_scale_type
           return session_info
   ```
2. Override `setScale` function:

   ```
   /* @odoo-module */

   import CalendarModel from '@calendar/js/calendar_model';
   import { session } from "@web/session";

   CalendarModel.include({

       setScale: function (scale) {
           if (!_.contains(this.scales, scale)) {
               scale = session.calendar_scale_type;
           }
           this._super(scale);
       },

   });
   ```

Comment: thanks to your advice, i did it. thank you.

Comment: can you give me advice on this question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73766276/odoo-how-to-replace-standard-discuss-textarea-by-froala-editor).
if you can develop it, how it will be cost?