# Odoo: how to replace standard discuss textarea by froala editor?

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-15

I want to extend the message field to do from this to this

[image][image]

in file `addons\mail\static\src\components\composer_text_input\composer_text_input.xml` there is a template with current textarea:

```
<t t-name="mail.ComposerTextInput" owl="1">
    <div class="o_ComposerTextInput">
        <t t-if="composerView">
            <t t-if="composerView.hasSuggestions">
                <ComposerSuggestionList
                    composerViewLocalId="props.composerViewLocalId"
                    isBelow="props.hasMentionSuggestionsBelowPosition"
                />
            </t>
            <textarea class="o_ComposerTextInput_textarea o_ComposerTextInput_textareaStyle" t-att-class="{ 'o-composer-is-compact': props.isCompact }" t-esc="composerView.composer.textInputContent" t-att-placeholder="textareaPlaceholder" t-on-click="_onClickTextarea" t-on-focusin="_onFocusinTextarea" t-on-focusout="_onFocusoutTextarea" t-on-keydown="_onKeydownTextarea" t-on-keyup="_onKeyupTextarea" t-on-input="_onInputTextarea" t-ref="textarea"/>
            <!--
                 This is an invisible textarea used to compute the composer
                 height based on the text content. We need it to downsize
                 the textarea properly without flicker.
            -->
            <textarea class="o_ComposerTextInput_mirroredTextarea o_ComposerTextInput_textareaStyle" t-att-class="{ 'o-composer-is-compact': props.isCompact }" t-esc="composerView.composer.textInputContent" t-ref="mirroredTextarea" disabled="1"/>
        </t>
    </div>
</t>
```

here is an example how it works in pure HTML file (2 files are placed in the same directory as a *.html file):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <textarea id="example"></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            var editor = new FroalaEditor('#example');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

problem is that when I insert that code, piece like that:

```
<link href="froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

odoo can't find it, line with styles also doesn't work.
i tried also to paste code from froala_editor.pkgd.min.js in  tag. In pure HTML it works, in odoo .xml not.

What I`m doing wrong?

(UPDATE) error while adding froala_editor.pkgd.min.js file in manifest
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the `mail.ComposerTextInput` template, set the textarea `id` attribute, and append the script initializing the froala editor after it.

***Example:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates>
    <t t-inherit="mail.ComposerTextInput" t-inherit-mode="extension">
        <xpath expr="//textarea[1]" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="id">example</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//textarea[1]" position="after">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var editor = new FroalaEditor('#example');
            </script>
        </xpath>
    </t>
</templates>
```

You will need to load the froala script and style and the template file using [assets](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/assets.html#bundles) in the manifest file

```
'assets': {
        'web.assets_backend': [
            'MODULE_NAME/static/src/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js',
            'MODULE_NAME/static/src/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css',
        ],
        'web.assets_qweb': [
            "MODULE_NAME/static/src/xml/composer.xml",
        ],
    },
```

You will need to change the buttons' disposition and handle the vent listeners (enable the send button when you enter text in the froala editor). Odoo implemented the composer to work with a text area, probably you will need to make big changes

To test it, try to add an emoji so the button will be activated. You will notice that Odoo escaped the HTML content and it shows as text is in the message list.

To avoid that use the following JS script:

```js
/** @odoo-module **/

import { registerInstancePatchModel} from '@mail/model/model_core';


registerInstancePatchModel('mail.composer_view', 'Froala Composer View', {
    _getMessageData() {
        let postData = this._super(...arguments);
        postData.body = postData.body.replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/, ">");
        return postData
    },
});
```

Add it after the froala script in the manifest file.

Comment: i receive one problem. when i try to add "froala_editor.pkgd.min.js" in __manifest__.py, in my odoo in windows, all work correctly, but when i try do this on my work server (ubuntu + docker), odoo show me white screen and nothing else(i only received 1 error while logging and i manage to take a screenshot of error, before it dissapears, i add error in post). Did you have this problem before?

Comment: Does this happen only when you add the froala  CSS?

Comment: no, only when i add .js

Comment: Sorry I did not get that error while adding the froala script

Comment: Its strange, but when i take another file from archive "froala_editor.min.js", it start working. but it is not important anymore. As it turned out, the editor has only a free trial version, and on the production site he hides the buttons and asks to pay. As an alternative, I found another open source editor (Quill Editor), that works fine. It fit the code I had already written and now everything works great. Thanks again, without your advice it would have been very difficult to come to a decision.